# array with in an array in jqplot

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I have tried it several hours and couldn't find a solution.

I am trying to build a jqplot dateaxisrender graph.

From mvc controller we are getting strings  like this:

```
    return Json(new { grdYTicks, grdGrphPoints, grdXTicks, metricYTicks, metricXTicks, metricBrkDwnGrid, metricLegends, overVwData },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        );
```

For grdGrphPoints, we get data as below:

```
 grdGrphPoints =   "["08/19",17]|["08/21",31]|["08/26",6]|["09/09",40]|["09/23",21]|["09/26",21]|["10/07",19]|["10/10",1]|["10/22",1]"
```

These are all the data points that we have to give to jqplot.
I need to put this string into array variable as :

```
var obj = [["08/19",17]|["08/21",31]|["08/26",6]|["09/09",40]|["09/23",21]|["09/26",21]|["10/07",19]|["10/10",1]|["10/22",1]]
```

I tried with :

```
 var   obj = [jQuery.parseJSON(graphData["grdGrphPoints"])];
```

But this is giving error,

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

I am unable to convert the string to an array.

can some body pls advise urgently?

Thanks a lot in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grdGrphPoints variable should actually contain a string in this form:

`grdGrphPoints = "[[\"08/19\",17],[\"08/21\",31],[\"08/26\",6],[\"09/09\",40],[\"09/23\",21],[\"09/26\",21],[\"10/07\",19],[\"10/10\",1],[\"10/22\",1]]"`

And then you would have to remove the square brackets from

`var   obj = [jQuery.parseJSON(graphData["grdGrphPoints"])];`

which would then look like

`var   obj = jQuery.parseJSON(graphData["grdGrphPoints"]);`